# ANTLR4 - parse a file line-by-line

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I try to write a grammar to parse a file line by line.

My grammar looks like this:

```
grammar simple;

parse: (line NL)* EOF
line    
     : statement1     
     | statement2 
     |            // empty line           
     ;

statement1 : KW1 (INT|FLOAT);
statement2 : KW2 INT;

... 

NL          : '\r'? '\n';
WS          : (' '|'\t')-> skip; // toss out whitespace
```

If the last line in my input file does **not** have a newline, I get the following error message:

```
line xx:37 missing NL at <EOF>
```

Can somebody please explain, how to write a grammar that actually accepts the last line without newline

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't require `NL` to fall after the last `line`. This form is efficient, and simplified based on the fact that `line` can match the empty sequence (essentially the last `line` will *always* be the empty line).

```
// best if `line` can be empty
parse
  : line (NL line)* EOF
  ;
```

If `line` was not allowed to be empty, the following rule is efficient and performs the same operation:

```
// best if `line` cannot be empty
parse
  : (line (NL line)* NL?)? EOF
  ;
```

The following rule is equivalent for the case where `line` cannot be empty, but is much less efficient. I'm including it because I frequently see people write rules in this form where it's easy to see that the specific `NL` token which was made optional is the one following the last `line`.

```
// INEFFICIENT!
parse
  : (line NL)* (line NL?)? EOF
  ;
```